# position: sticky adds some space around element in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, sticky

#### Description

I have a `<header>` element which uses `position: sticky` to stick to the top of the page when the user scrolls past it. It somehow seems that in Chrome, said element does not display as intended, but rather adds some space around the top and left of the element. I managed to isolate the code from my CSS file to reproduce the bug and successfully reproduced it in Chrome (both Android and Windows 7 Desktop). Does anyone know why this is happening and if there is a solution to it?

#### Code Sample (available also as a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/chalarangelo/pen/wJqbvM))

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  display: block;
  height: 44px;
  background: #263238;
  color: #fafafa;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18), 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

header.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1101;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Blah blah</p>

<header class="sticky"> 
  <button>Home</button> 
  <button>About</button>
</header>

<!-- some spacing to allow users to scroll the page -->
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

#### Screenshots of the bug and intended behavior

The below image shows what the `<header>` element should look like on all browsers. Currently, Chrome does not seem to display this correctly (see next image).

[image: Intended behavior]

This image show what the `<header>` element looks like in Chrome. Notice the little space left to the left and top of the element.

[image]

#### Notes

- As far as I can tell, the rest of my CSS does not really interfere with the styling of the element, as you can see from the Codepen and the snippet provided.
- Due to the fact that this bug appeared in my CSS framework, the name and logo of the project have been removed from screenshots to avoid self-promotion.
- Provided the previous note, I would prefer a pure CSS solution (no Javascript or changes to the HTML) to the problem, unless there is none.
- I can successfully reproduce the bug in Chrome 56.0.2924.87 on Android 5.0.2 and in Chrome 57.0.2987.98 (64-bit) on Windows 7 (64-bit).

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem in Chrome... no margins at all!

Comment: @andreas I can reproduce on both of my devices, as stated. what version of Chrome are you on and what platform?

Comment: Chrome 57.0.2987.98 on Win10

Comment: Your code works as expected in Chrome, Firefox and Opera on Windows 10. It also fails miserably on Internet Explorer 11. Latest versions on all browsers.

Comment: check this http://caniuse.com/#search=position%3A%20sticky before you use `position:sticky`, it is not compatible with all browsers.

Comment: I can still reproduce the bug easily in Chrome 56.0.2924.87 on Android (device won't update further) and Chrome 57.0.2987.98 (64-bit) on Win7.

Comment: I'm sorry that you're having this issue, but if you need to support older browsers and operating systems, it's usually a bad idea to use modern features.

Comment: @AndreiV on the contrary, I am running this code on the latest versions of Chrome I can get my hands on and accept the fact that it will not run on older browsers. Is it possible that this is an OS problem? I will try to reproduce in Chromium on Ubuntu 16.04 later in another device, but I don't think I'll notice any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I can see what you are trying to say, `box:shadow` is evil in this case. I assume you can't remove this, so I have added `overflow:hidden` in `body` css.
have a look at the snippet below.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: red
}

header {
  display: block;
  height: 44px;
  background: #263238;
  color: #fafafa;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18), 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

header.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1101;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Blah blah</p>

<header class="sticky"> 
  <button>Home</button> 
  <button>About</button>
</header>

<!-- some spacing to allow users to scroll the page -->
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: Wow, this does actually seem to deal with the issue. Is it possible that `overflow: hidden;` will cause any complications if added in `body`?

Comment: Any content goes out of view port area will not be visible on screen, as this  will disable the scrollbars, I hope you are using responsive design so this hardly matter.

Comment: I am using responsive design, so I expect that this will not really break anything. Thanks a lot for helping me figure this one out!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Here is how I fixed it.

Adding `overflow: hidden` to `body` will disable scrolling. So, I added only `overflow-x: hidden`

```css
html,body{
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

I hope it helps others.

Answer (score -4):

Replace the unsupported `position: sticky` with `position: fixed; width: 100%;` and try it on all browsers. As @aje mentioned always check browser compatibility before using experimental/new css3 style.

Comment: The problem is not about browser support, as I can reproduce it in Chrome 57, which does fully support `position: sticky`. Using `position: fixed` will not really deal with the situation in an optimal manner, as the header will not behave as intended, but just display as intended.

Comment: Replace _sticky_ with _fixed_ does not solve the problem using _sticky_, which I am sure the down voter used as argument.